# How do I edit my default RSS Feed?

Tags: rss

I want to edit some outputs such as the content or description fields.

Do I have to make a custom rss feed just to change one thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the content shown in a feed, use the [`the_content_feed`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_feed/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', function ( $content, $feed_type ) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if ( $feed_type === 'atom' )
         $content = 'something else';
    else
         $content = wp_trim_words( $content, 30 );

    return $content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

The above is purely an example of some of the (bizarre) things you might want to do.